# Fortran rank mismatch error

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran, plato

I receive the following error

```
Compiling file: tropic.f
Warning: Extension: Tab character in format at (1)
C:\Users\Marchant\Desktop\tropic.f(432) : error - Expected a right parenthesis in expression at column 72 
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'tk' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 't' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 'tk' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)
Warning: Rank mismatch in argument 't' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)
```

Compilation failed.

in this program,

```
     dimension ts1(3),ts2(3),ta1(3),ta2(3),out(14,300)
      real lwc, lambda
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc
      common /param2/ pbot,ptop,dp,gam, bt,ct,tao,a21,lambda,lwc
      common /heat/ beta,olr1,olr2,alb0,albgr,expo1,expo2,alb1,alb2

      pbot=1.0e5
      ptop=2.0e4
      dp=pbot-ptop
      open(12,file='tropic.in',form='formatted')
      read(12,*) itermx, delt, iprint
      read(12,*) lambda, gam, bt, ct, a1
      read(12,*)  beta,olr1,olr2,alb0,albgr,expo1,expo2
      write(*,*) 'olr1=',olr1,', olr2=',olr2,', expo1=',expo1,', expo2='
     1 ,expo2

c **  Set relative areas of convecting a1 and nonconvecting a2 regions.
c      a1=.3
      tao=265.
      alpha=0.06
      alpha2=alpha/2.
      alpha1=1.-alpha
c      expo1=80.
c      expo2=80.
      expa1=0.
      expa2=0.
      co=4.2e7
      ca=1.0e7
      xkap=0.288
      rvap=461.
      cp=1004.
      rgas=287.
      grav=9.81
c      gam=1.0e-3
c      lambda=1.0e3
      pr=1.0e5
      tr=300.
      xl=2.5e6
      write(*,*) ' gam=',gam
c**   structure of output array
c     out(1)=a1;   2=gam;  3=lambda
c     4=ts1        5=ts2   6=alb1     7=alb2
c     8=r1         9=r2    10=ts1tend  11=ts2tend
c    13=thet1     14=thet2
      ikase=0
c *********  BIG LOOP  ****************
      do 888 nn=1,2
      a1=0.1+0.2*nn

      do 888 ll=1,7
c      gam=1.0e-3*facg
      gam=1/1024.*2.0**(ll-1)
      do 888 mm=1,7
c      lambda=1.0e+3*facl
      lambda=64*2.0**(mm-1)
c      write(*,*) '*******************************'
c      write(*,*) 'GAM=',gam,',  LAMBDA=',lambda,',  A1=',a1
      a2=1.-a1
      a21=a2/a1
      a12=a1/a2

c  initialize variables
      do i = 1,3
      ts1(i)=301.
      ts2(i)=300.
      ta1(i)=302.
      ta2(i)=300.
      end do
      is=1
      js=2


      tdelto=2.*delt/co
      tdelta=2.*delt/ca

c      write(*,999) ts1(js),ts2(js),ta1(js),ta2(js),r1,r2,ra1,ra2
 999  format(1x,9f8.1)
c      write(*,*) pbot,ptop,dp,pr,gam,bt,ct,tao,a21,lambda,lwc

       ikase=ikase+1

c***   Time Loop  *****

      do 1000 it=1,itermx
      dta=ta1(js)-ta2(js)
      dto=ts1(js)-ts2(js)
      call radiat(ts1(js),ts2(js),ta1(js),ta2(js),r1,r2,ra1,ra2)
      call theta(ts1(js),ts2(js),ta1(js),ta2(js),demdp,demd2,deddp)
c**  Note that demdp = del(theta)/grav      
      ts1(3)=ts1(is)+tdelto*(r1-gam*dto*cp*demdp-expo1)
      ts2(3)=ts2(is)+tdelto*(r2+a12*gam*dto*cp*demdp-expo2)
c      ta1(3)=ta1(is)+tdelta*(ra1-a21*gam*dto*cp*demdp-expa1)
c      ta2(3)=ta2(is)+tdelta*(ra2+gam*dto*cp*deddp-expa2)
c  apply Robert/Asselin filter
      ts1(js)=ts1(js)*alpha1 +alpha2*(ts1(3)+ts1(is))
      ts2(js)=ts2(js)*alpha1 +alpha2*(ts2(3)+ts2(is))
c      if((it-1)/iprint*iprint.eq.it-1) then
      if((it.eq.itermx)) then
      time=(it-1)*delt/86400.
      ts1tend=(r1-gam*dto*cp*demdp-expo1)*86400./co
      ts2tend=(r2+a12*gam*dto*cp*demdp-expo2)*86400./co
c      ta1tend=(-a21*gam*dto*cp*demdp)
c      ta2tend=( gam*dto*cp*demdp)
      thet1=thet(ts1,qsat(ts1,pbot),pbot)
      thet2=thet(ts2,qsat(ts2,pbot),pbot)
c**   structure of output array
c     out(1)=a1;   2=gam;  3=lambda
c     4=ts1        5=ts2   6=alb1     7=alb2
c     8=r1         9=r2    10=ts1tend  11=ts2tend
c    12=thet1     13=thet2
c    Set up array
      out(1,ikase)=a1
      out(2,ikase)=gam
      out(3,ikase)=lambda
      out(4,ikase)=ts1(js)
      out(5,ikase)=ts2(js)
      out(6,ikase)=alb1
      out(7,ikase)=alb2
      out(8,ikase)=r1
      out(9,ikase)=r2
      out(10,ikase)=ts1tend
      out(11,ikase)=ts2tend
      out(12,ikase)=thet1
      out(13,ikase)=thet2
      out(14,ikase)=qsat(ts1(js),pr)


c      write(*,*)  'Day=',time, ',  iter=',it
c      write(*,*) a21,gam,dto,cp,demdp
c      write(*,*) 'demdp, demd2,deddp', demdp, demd2,deddp
c      write(*,*) 'lwc=',lwc,alb1, alb2
c*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x**********
c      write(*,*) '   ts1,    ts2,    ta1,    ta2,     r1,     r2,    ra1,
c     1     ra2'
c      write(*,999) ts1(3),ts2(3),ta1(3),ta2(3),r1,r2,ra1,ra2
c      write(*,999) ts1(js),ts2(js),ta1(js),ta2(js),r1,r2,ra1,ra2
c      write(*,998) ts1tend,ts2tend,ta1tend,ta2tend, thet1, thet2
  998 format(1x,8f10.5)
      endif
c **  Update Variables
      is=3-is
      js=3-js
      ts1(js)=ts1(3)
      ts2(js)=ts2(3)
      ta1(js)=ta1(3)
      ta2(js)=ta2(3)

 1000 continue
 888  continue
      open(13,file='tropic.out',form='formatted')
c*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x**********
      write(*,*) '   A1        gam     lambda   ts1    ts2     alb1     
     1alb2    r1      r2    ts1tend  ts2tend  thet1   thet2   qsat'
      write(13,*) '   A1        gam     lambda   ts1    ts2     alb1     
     1alb2    r1      r2    ts1tend  ts2tend  thet1   thet2   qsat'
      do ii=1,ikase
      xkrap=out(2,ii)*out(3,ii)
      write(*,789) (out(j,ii),j=1,14),xkrap
      write(13,789) (out(j,ii),j=1,14),xkrap
  789 format(1x,f6.1,f9.5,7f9.2,2f9.5,2f8.2,2f8.4)
      enddo

      stop
      end

c ******************************************************
      subroutine theta(ts1,ts2,ta1,ta2,demdp,demd2,deddp)
c ** This subroutine finds the theta gradients
      real lwc, lambda
      common /param2/ pbot,ptop,dp,gam, bt,ct,tao,a21,lambda,lwc
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc

      demdp=(thet(ts1,qsat(ts1,pbot),pbot)-thet(ts2,qsat(ts2,pbot),
     1 pbot))/9.81
c     1 pbot))/dp
      demd2=(thet(ta1,0.001,ptop)-thet(ts1,qsat(ts1,pbot),pbot))
     1 /9.81
c     1 /dp
      deddp=(thet(ts1,0.00001,ptop)-thet(ts2,0.00001,pbot))/9.81
c     1 /dp
      return
      end
c ******************************************************
      subroutine radiat(ts1,ts2,ta1,ta2,r1,r2,ra1,ra2)
      real lwc, lambda
      common /param2/ pbot,ptop,dp,gam, bt,ct,tao,a21,lambda,lwc
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc
      common /heat/ beta,olr1,olr2,alb0,albgr,expo1,expo2,alb1,alb2


      dta=ta1-ta2
      dto=ts1-ts2
      if(dto.gt.0.0) then
c **  radiation parameterization  for atmosphere
      ra1=-40-bt*(ta1-tao)+ct*(ts1-(ta1+29))
      ra2=-200-bt*(ta2-tao)+ct*(ts2-(ta2+29))
c **  Get liquid water content
c      lwc=lambda*a21*gam*abs(dto)*qsat(ts1,pr)
c **  Get albedo as function of LWC
      alb2=alb0
      alb1=alb0+lambda*gam*abs(dto)*qsat(ts1,pr)
      if(alb1.gt.0.75) alb1=0.75
      r1=400.*(1.-alb1)-olr1-beta*(ts1-300.)
      r2=400.*(1.-alb2)-olr2-beta*(ts2-300.)
      else
c **  here ts2 is hotter than ts1
c **  radiation parameterization  for atmosphere
      ra1=-200-bt*(ta1-tao)+ct*(ts1-(ta1+29))
      ra2=-40-bt*(ta2-tao)+ct*(ts2-(ta2+29))
c **  Get liquid water content
c      lwc=lambda*gam*abs(dto)*qsat(ts2,pr)
c **  Get albedo as function of LWC
      alb1=alb0
      alb2=alb0+lambda*gam*abs(dto)*qsat(ts2,pr)
      if(alb2.gt.0.75) alb2=0.75
      r1=400.*(1.-alb1)-olr2-beta*(ts1-300.)
      r2=400.*(1.-alb2)-olr1-beta*(ts2-300.)
      endif
c      write(*,*) 'lwc=',lwc,', alb1,2=',alb1,alb2,', r,ra-',r1,r2,ra1,ra2

      return
      end

c*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x*********x**********
c*************************************************************
      function temp(the,rv,p)
c**  Function calculates temperature given thetaE, rv and p
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc
      temp=the/((pr/p)**xkap*exp(xl*rv/(cp*tr)))
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      function thet(t,rv,p)
c**  Function calculates thetaE given t, rv and p
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc
      thet=t*(pr/p)**xkap*exp(xl*rv/(cp*tr))
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      function thets(t,p)
c**  Function calculates thetaEsaturate given t and p
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc
      if(t.lt.273.15) then
      es=esice(t)
      else
      es=esat(t)
      endif
      rs=0.622*es/(p-es)
      thets=t*(pr/p)**xkap*exp(xl*rs/(cp*tr))
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      subroutine plevs(p,xlp,dlp,dp)
c**  Subroutine to set pressure levels
      parameter(ilx=25)
      dimension p(ilx),xlp(ilx),dlp(ilx),dp(ilx)
      write(*,*) 'Setting Pressure Levels'
      write(*,*) '    i    p(i)    dp(i)    logp      dlogp'
      pmin=2000.
      pmax=101300.
      delpo=pmax-pmin
      delp=delpo/(ilx-1)
      do i=1,ilx
      p(i)=pmin+(i-1.)*delp
      xlp(i)=alog(p(i))
      end do
      do i=1,ilx-1
      dlp(i)=xlp(i+1)-xlp(i)
      dp(i)=p(i+1)-p(i)
      end do
      dlp(ilx)=0.0
      do i=1,ilx
      write(*,*) i,p(i),dp(i),xlp(i),dlp(i)
      end do
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      subroutine radini(teq,p,t,sst)
c**  Calculates variables needed by radiation relaxation code
      parameter (ilx=25)
      dimension p(ilx),t(ilx),teq(ilx)
      do i=1,ilx
      if(p(i).lt.12000.) then
      teq(i)=t(i)
c      elseif(p(i).gt.80000.) then
      else
      teq(i)=t(i)-10.
c      teq(i)=t(i)-(p(ilx)/10000.)*2.
      endif
      end do
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      subroutine initlz(the,rt,rs,t,rv,p,sst)
c**  Subroutine to set initial values of all variables
      parameter (ilx=25)
      dimension the(ilx),rt(ilx),rs(ilx),t(ilx),rv(ilx),
     1 p(ilx)
      common /params/xkap,pr,tr,xl,cp,rgas,grav,taue,taus,taup,tauc
      ttrop=200.
      tsurf=300.
      ptrop=10000.
      dtdp=(tsurf-ttrop)/(p(ilx)-ptrop)
      relhum=0.80
c**  Set T(p)
      do i=1,ilx
      if(p(i).lt.ptrop) then
      t(i)=200.+10.*(ptrop-p(i))/(ptrop-p(1))
      else
      t(i)=200.+dtdp*(p(i)-ptrop)
      endif
      end do
c**  Next calculate vapor mixing ratio and thetaE
      write(*,*) 'index,  pressure, temp.,   vapor mr, thetaE'
      do i=1,ilx
      if(p(i).lt.ptrop) then
      rfrac=0.05
      else
      rfrac=relhum
      endif
      if(t(i).lt.273.) then
      es=esice(t(i))
      else
      es=esat(t(i))
      endif
      rv(i)=rfrac*0.622*es/(p(i)-es)
      rs(i)=0.622*es/(p(i)-es)
      rt(i)=rv(i)
      the(i)=t(i)*(pr/p(i))**xkap*exp(xl*rv(i)/(cp*tr))
      write(*,100) i,p(i),t(i),rv(i),the(i)
  100 format(1x,i3,f12.1,f7.1,e13.3,f7.1)
      end do
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      function signum(x)
c**  Hankel function
      if(x.eq.0) then
      signum=1.
      else
      signum=(abs(x)+x)*0.5/abs(x)
      endif
      return
      end

c*************************************************************
      subroutine zero(x,n)
      dimension x(n)
      do i=1,n
      x(i)=0.0
      end do
      return
      end

C#######################################################################

    FUNCTION ESICE(TK)                                                      

C   THIS FUNCTION RETURNS THE SATURATION VAPOR PRESSURE WITH RESPECT TO 
C   ICE ESICE (Pascals) GIVEN THE TEMPERATURE T (Kelvin). DLH 11.19.97
C   THE FORMULA USED IS BASED UPON THE INTEGRATION OF THE CLAUSIUS-     
C   CLAPEYRON EQUATION BY GOFF AND GRATCH.  THE FORMULA APPEARS ON P.350
C   OF THE SMITHSONIAN METEOROLOGICAL TABLES, SIXTH REVISED EDITION,    
C   1963.                                                               

    DATA CTA,EIS/273.15,6.1071/                                            

C   CTA = DIFFERENCE BETWEEN KELVIN AND CELSIUS TEMPERATURE             
C   EIS = SATURATION VAPOR PRESSURE (MB) OVER A WATER-ICE MIXTURE AT 0C 

    DATA C1,C2,C3/9.09718,3.56654,0.876793/                                

C   C1,C2,C3 = EMPIRICAL COEFFICIENTS IN THE GOFF-GRATCH FORMULA        
c**** Convert to Celsius
c        tc=t-273.15
    IF (TK.LE.CTA) GO TO 5                                                   
    ESICE = 99999.                                                         
    WRITE(6,3)ESICE                                                        
    3   FORMAT(' SATURATION VAPOR PRESSURE FOR ICE CANNOT BE COMPUTED',   
     1         /' FOR TEMPERATURE > 0C. ESICE =',F7.0)                   
    RETURN                                                                 
    5   CONTINUE                                                          

C   FREEZING POINT OF WATER (K)                                         

    TF = CTA                                                               

C   GOFF-GRATCH FORMULA                                                 

    RHS = -C1*(TF/TK-1.)-C2*ALOG10(TF/TK)+C3*(1.-TK/TF)+ALOG10(EIS)        
    ESI = 10.**RHS                                                         
    IF (ESI.LT.0.) ESI = 0.                                                
    ESICE = ESI*100.
    RETURN                                                                 
    END                                                                    

C#######################################################################

    FUNCTION ESAT(TK)

C   THIS FUNCTION RETURNS THE SATURATION VAPOR PRESSURE OVER            
C   WATER (Pa) GIVEN THE TEMPERATURE (Kelvin).  DLH 11.19.97
C   THE ALGORITHM IS DUE TO NORDQUIST, W.S.,1973: "NUMERICAL APPROXIMA- 
C   TIONS OF SELECTED METEORLOLGICAL PARAMETERS FOR CLOUD PHYSICS PROB- 
C   LEMS," ECOM-5475, ATMOSPHERIC SCIENCES LABORATORY, U.S. ARMY        
C   ELECTRONICS COMMAND, WHITE SANDS MISSILE RANGE, NEW MEXICO 88002.   

    IF (TD.NE. 99999.0) THEN                                                
C   IF (TD.NE.-1001.0) THEN
c**** Convert to Celsius
c   TK = TD+273.15                                                         
    P1 = 11.344-0.0303998*TK                                               
    P2 = 3.49149-1302.8844/TK                                              
    C1 = 23.832241-5.02808*ALOG10(TK)                                      
    ESAT = 100.*10.**(C1-1.3816E-7*10.**P1+8.1328E-3*10.**P2-2949.076/TK)       
    else
          esat = 0.
    END IF                                                                 
    RETURN                                                                 
    END                                                                    
C#######################################################################
        function qsat(tk,p)
        qsat=esat(tk)*0.622/p
        return
        end
```

Can someone show me how to fix this? its a fortran77 file being compiled in mingw gfortran

Comment: please try to find a smaller minimal working examle next time. Your lines are too long for Fortran 77, there is an option to change this limit.

Comment: I dont understand, this was written in fortran 77 by another party years ago, they used fortran 77  and now I am using gfortran, how can the lines be too long for fortran77 if that is what created it?

Comment: Becasue they did it wrong or you copied their code wrong.

Comment: But really, try to find a MINIMAL working example, that still shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At least the line

```
      ESAT = 100.*10.**(C1-1.3816E-7*10.**P1+8.1328E-3*10.**P2-2949.076/TK)
```

is too long for FORTRAN 77 standard. At least when the statement starts at column 7. In your code it appears to start earlier, but that is wrong.

Break it,

```
      ESAT = 100.*10.**(C1-1.3816E-7*10.**P1+
     *                  8.1328E-3*10.**P2-2949.076/TK)
```

or use an option like

`-ffixed-line-length-132`

to make the limit larger (it is non-standard!).

Also many of your statements appear to start on earlier column than 7. This may be a copy-paste error to this page, it may be due to the non-conforming tab characters the compiler warns about. If it is not the case, correct it too, they must start at column 7 or further. For example, this is very strange:

```
    IF (TD.NE. 99999.0) THEN                                                
C   IF (TD.NE.-1001.0) THEN
```

There may be other errors, but your code is simply too long and cannot be compiled by copy-paste.

Comment: the file tropic.f was sent to me in an email, I opened it to copy the code using programmers notepad, this is strange that the author says he is running it fine but I am getting errors, using the exact same file,

Comment: The FORTRAN 77 standard required lines of 72 characters or less.  It was extremely common to override this.  But you have to use the particular option for your compiler to do so.   Tabs are illegal characters according to the standard.  Some compilers might accept them, others not.  Look up on the web the source code layout rules for FORTRAN 77.

Comment: Thanks, I see, I am using the gfortran MinGW compiler buy running gfortran tropic.f, forgive me I am a extremely new beginner with all of this, if anyone can help me get this code working with gfortran, I am willing to reimburse for time spent,

Comment: Did you try the option `-ffixed-line-length-132`?

Comment: See thats how bad I am at fortran, I only ever learned matlab hehe.. Do I add -ffixed-line-length-132 to my main program as a line entry or is that entered in the mingw command window? I inherited this "ancient" code